# How to hide Webkit warnings in node packages?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webkit

I'm currently developing an Express application with Typescript transpiling into NodeJS thanks to Webkit.

The problem is that I start getting too much warnings that are related to the packages I'm using, and not about my own app. Here is a sample:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 81:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/app.ts
 @ ./src/server.ts
 @ multi webpack/hot/poll?1000 ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fast-crc32c' in '/Users/.../node_modules/hash-stream-validation'
 @ ./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./src/connectors/google_storage.ts
 @ ./src/server/routes/expose_data_handler.ts
 @ ./src/app.ts
 @ ./src/server.ts
 @ multi webpack/hot/poll?1000 ./src/server.ts
```

Is there any way to hide package related warnings?

Here is the **webpack.js** config I'm using:

```js
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const ENTRY_FILE = 'src/server.ts';

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000', path.join(__dirname, ENTRY_FILE)],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    fs: 'commonjs fs',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  target: 'node',
};
```

P.S.: Please tell in the comment if I'm missing some useful information to add.